# Is there a Hausdorff topological field without the following property?

Tags: reference-request, topological-rings

Let us say a given topological (commutative) ring $K$ has property $P$ if for each $f \in x + (x^2)(K[x])$, such $f$ is injective on some neighborhood of $0 \in K$ when viewed as a function $f : K \rightarrow K$.

From what I understand:

- Any topological subring of a topological commutative ring with property $P$ also has property $P$.
- The field of complex numbers has property $P$.
- According to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4746256/896770) to my earlier question, any topological field which is complete with respect to a non-archimedean absolute value has property $P$. (E.g. the $p$-adic number fields.)

I was wondering, what would be an example of a Hausdorff topological field which does *not* have property $P$?

Comment: I would try to rescue the route given in my answer and comment to your linked question. The problem is that the notion of (strict) differentiability is not standardly defined for topological fields; but I think they could be, using ideas of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3249242/96384 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3757356/96384.